# How to prove that $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ is monotonically decreasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$.
I am pretty sure it monotonically decreases. But how can we prove it?

Comment: @lulu - Could you elaborate? Mine is not the same and mine is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Note that $1+\frac 1x=\frac {x+1}x$ is the reciprocal of $\frac x{x+1}$.  And note that for a positive sequence, $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing if and only if $\frac 1{a_n}$ is increasing.

Comment: @lulu - you are correct. Now I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \text{ be a sequence, where }$ $x_n=(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$.Observe that $x_n=\frac{1}{y_n}$, where $y_n=(\frac{n+1}{n})^n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. It is proved that the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}^{\star}}$ is stricly increasing to $e$. As this sequence is strictly increasing, the reciprocal of it, $x_n$ is strictly decreasing to $\frac{1}{e}$($\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{y_n}}=\frac{1}{e})$.

Comment: I am not sure your reasoning is correct, e.g. $0.9*1.2=1.08$

Comment: I have changed the solution and I am sure that this one is correct.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates or questions without context and where the OP does not show effort. It goes against the regulations of this site.